# Передать переменную из URL в val()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно чтобы при вызове `site.com/?Email=ivan.naumov@gmail.com`
передавался параметр в `$("#id-1").val`.

```
setInterval(function(){ins();}, 7000);
$("#id-1").attr("name", "Email");
$("#id-2").attr("name", "Message");
$("#id-1").val("ivan.naumov@gmail.com"); $("#id-2").focus();});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split('=');
        if (decodeURIComponent(pair[0]) == variable) {
            return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        }
    }
    console.log('Query variable %s not found', variable);
}

getQueryVariable('Email')
```

Answer (score 0):

Если Email=ivan.naumov@gmail.com - это последний или единственный параметр в get-запросе, то получить "мыло" можно вот такой конструкцией:

```
let mail = window.location.href.split('=').pop();
```

Ну и передать потом переменную в $("#id-1").val():

```
$("#id-1").val(mail);
```

Если же параметр не один или находится где-то в середине get-запроса, то можно сделать так:

```
let mail = '';
let url = window.location.href.split(/\?|&|\=/); //получаем массив из всех элементов адреса
for(let i = 0; i < url.length; i++) { //в цикле проверяем
  if(url[i].indexOf('@') != -1) { //есть ли элемент, содержащий "собаку"
    mail = url[i];
  }
}
$("#id-1").val(mail);
```

Answer (score 0):

Атрибут `id` в принципе не нужен, когда есть `name`:

```js
// const params = (new URL(window.location)).searchParams; 
const params = (new URL('https://site.com/?Email=ivan.naumov@gmail.com&Message=Hello')).searchParams; 
for (let [key, value] of params.entries())
  $(`input[name="${key}"]`).val(value);   // document.querySelector(`input[name="${key}"]`).value = value;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="Email">
<input name="Message">
```

p.s.: Метод `URLSearchParams.entries()` уже поддерживается всеми популярными браузерами (как и деструктурирование, и шаблонные строки), хотя он еще не включен в стандарт.

Comment: В ответе нет проверок (так как в вопросе нет воспроизводимого примера), но они нужны в варианте без jQuery, с `querySelector`: при отсутствующем инпуте будет бросаться исключение.